# User-Generated Models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a database that keeps track of items for a user.

For example, a user might want to keep track of their cars and the color, make and year of it. They will first create a cars "model", and they can now add as many new cars as they want. When they make a car, they will be prompted to input the color, make and year as well as generic item information.

The user might also want to keep track of their cats. But the cat "model" has different fields than the car "model." Maybe they need to keep track of the weight and breed of their cats. When they want to add an item of type cat to the database, I will prompt them to input the weight and breed NOT color, make and year.

I'm not very experienced with rails or SQL, but I was thinking when a user tells me they want to keep track of cars, I could create a cars table with color make and year. When they input a car, I would store the car as a generic item and also keep a reference to the cars table where I would store the color make and year. Not quite sure how I would implement though, so I'm open to any new ideas. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are looking for multitable-inheritance. There are couple of gems that will make it easier to implement: https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation

Comment: @BroiSatse I looked at the ReadMe and it looks like if I want to add a new type of product (ie: "pens") I need to create the class the backend. I was hoping for a way to create product types through user input.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case SQL database is no good here as it requires tables with fixed schemas. You are looking for NoSQL, mongo might be a good choice - it allows you to create records with different schemas within a single index. You can try implementing it in the SQL, however it will require quite  a lot of work.

Comment: Broistatse if you put an answer with the multitable stuff, I'll upvote for you

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right that you will need to create a table for both a car and cat, each with their own columns. 
Rails comes with Active Record to facilitate the creation of databases. Active record is really easy to use and has some great [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).
For example, to create a table for a car, you will have to create a car model first. 
To get Active Record to create a model, you just use the following command in terminal:

`$ rails g model Car color:string make:string year:integer`

This model is stored in app/models. Don't forget to migrate your database after you create the model.
In order for a user to enter the properties of the instance, you will need to use form_for. Documentation for a form_for can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html). To use a form_for you need to declare the instance for the model that you want to change and the method you are going to use once the form has been submitted. You then follow this up with some input fields which are all associated with a property of the instance. The example in the documentation is a pretty good one.

```
<%= form_for @article, url: {action: "create"}, html: {class: "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12" %>
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's a great explanation on how to make models and forms in rails. However, I don't want to be generating new models when the user wants to create a new item type in the back end.


I was hoping to allow users to specify attributes their item types (ie: color, make, model) in through the application itself. Then, these will allow them to save new items in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with something called `Meta` models - whereby you have `app/models/meta.rb` which allows you to invoke models the user defines in the db.

I've had this running, but it's not super efficient.

I'll tell you about it; maybe it will give you some ideas.............

--

Each model can be stripped down to set of 2 common attributes - `title` & `value`:

```
#app/models/node.rb
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns id | type | title | value | created_at | updated_at
end
```

This is the *very* base of the models you wish to use (`car` / `cat` etc).

For example, you could make a `node` have the following stats:

```
# id | type      | title | value            | created_at | updated_at
# 1  | Meta::Cat | Greg  | A new cat we got | 15/12/2015 | 15/12/2015
# 2  | Meta::Cat | Pip   | A little kitten  | 16/12/2015 | 16/12/2015
# 3  | Meta::Car | F480  | The red Ferrari  | 10/12/2015 | 10/12/2015
```

This will give you a base set of data which you can then append different associations to.

And yes, the new associations can be stored in the `node` datatable too.

So in fact, you could have the following:

```
#app/models/meta.rb
class Meta
    classes = %w(cat car)
    if classes.any?
        classes.each do |klass| #-> "class" is reserved
            self.const_set klass.titleize, Class.new(Node) do
                belongs_to :user
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This will programmatically create the `Cat` and `Car` classes, which can be called with `Meta::Cat` etc as required.

I guess this is how you could get your different "base" models.

If you then wanted to add extra associations to that, you'd have to have extra data to make sure that you know which associations each model has.

I've not done this yet, but as you can see above, you can invoke a block which basically allows you to define different things in the pseudo-class:

--

So if you had another meta class called `Option`, you could use it to set the associations for each other class:

```
# 2  | Meta::Option | association | has_many :x   | 16/12/2015 | 16/12/2015
# 3  | Meta::Option | association | belongs_to :y | 10/12/2015 | 10/12/2015
```

I still need to think about how it will match the association, but in short, you'll be able to do the following:

```
#app/models/meta.rb
class Meta
    classes = %w(cat car)
    if classes.any?
        classes.each do |klass| #-> "class" is reserved
            self.const_set klass.titleize, Class.new(Node) do
                #-> Node.where(name: "association").pluck(:value)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This is known as [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) (or it might be pseudoprogramming) and is something which could be done; whether it's efficient is another question entirely.